# what is the difference between angular-show and angular-bind?

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angularjs. I have a doubt in ng-show and ng-bind

```
    Here in this code it binds value and displays it.
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        <p ng-bind="name"></p>

    Here in this code it appends from Hello 
        <h1 ng-show="sometext">Hello {{ sometext }}</h1>
```

I want to know the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

This is different than what `ng-show` does in that there's no replacement done for `ng-show`, just a state toggle based on a boolean value.

> The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute. The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the .ng-hide CSS class onto the element.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Answer (score 0):

The ng-show shows or hides the given element based on the expression provided, the ng-bind tells AngularJs to replace the text content of the specified element with the value of a given expression.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bind` will just replace the text in the element with the value from the model, `ng-show` is used to control whether an element is shown and is based on Boolean (truthy and falsey) values.  It just so happens that as sometext contains a value it is truthy so it will also show the element.

Answer (score 0):

They're completely different:

`ng-bind`, binds the value in the referenced model to the content of the elemend where the bin  is, it's the same of having:

```
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

`ng-show` (as well as `ng-hide`) is used when you want something to appear or not given some conditional expression. So in that case, that `h1` will only appear if "sometext" is an expression evaluated to `true`